# Problem with multi-table MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. Here is the relevant information needed for each.

### items

prod_id
order_id
item_qty
primarykey is prod_id

### orders

order_id
order_date
order_status
acct_id
primary-key is order_id 
key is acct_id

### accounts

acct_id
is_wholesale
primary-key is acct_id

items is linked to order by the order_id and orders is linked to accounts via acct_id

I need to sum item_qty for all items where prod_id=464 and the order stats is not 5 and where the is_wholesale is 0 and the order_date is between two dates. Im struggling with this and would appreciate any help. Here is what I have but it's not working correctly:

```
SELECT SUM(items.item_qty) as qty
  FROM items
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = items.order_id
LEFT JOIN accounts on orders.acct_id = accounts.acct_id
WHERE items.prod_id =451
  AND orders.order_date >= '$from_date'
  AND orders.order_date <= '$to_date'
  AND orders.order_status <>5
  AND accounts.is_wholesale=0;
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume you are looking for something other than the obvious need to change `= 451` to `= 464`?

Comment: Which of these columns is the primary key for each table, especially the items table? Maybe posting SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table will help.

Comment: I'd change the LEFT JOIN to JOIN, but I don't see what's not working for you without sample data.

Comment: What are the values of $from_date and $to_date? Can you post the exact query that you are executing, after the variable substitutions have been made?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not working correctly'? What is it doing? Wrong result? Too high or too low? Error? What error?

Comment: the is_wholesale field is either set to 1 or 0 I ran the query from above and it returned 39932<br/> I ran it changing the is_wholesale=0 to is_wholesale=1 and it returned 82651<br/> I remove that part from the where clause completely and it returns 368612 which should just be the two previous added up

Comment: @mahle: Because you are using a LEFT JOIN the is_wholesale can also be NULL. Try changing the is_wholesale=0 to is_wholesale IS NULL and run the query again. You will get 246029, which accounts for the missing values. As OMG Ponies said, you probably want an INNER JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Changing left to inner seemed to have made a difference.  Let me run some more tests to see.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thanks for your help.  It's fixed!

Comment: @mahle: I'm surprised that changing left to inner makes a difference because the way your query is structured prevents NULLs occuring. I suspect that this query was working all along. If you run your old query and your new query do you get different results?

Comment: @mahle: I've changed my answer to try to summarize what the error was for other people that might find this when searching.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK. Your query works correctly.

Your problem came from checking whether your query worked. You wrote another query that you believed summed both `is_wholesale = 0` and `is_wholesale = 1`:

```
SELECT SUM(items.item_qty) as qty
  FROM items
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = items.order_id
LEFT JOIN accounts on orders.acct_id = accounts.acct_id
WHERE items.prod_id =451
  AND orders.order_date >= '$from_date'
  AND orders.order_date <= '$to_date'
  AND orders.order_status <>5;
```

However this query contains an error. Changing the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` fixes the query. It is also good practice to write `INNER JOIN` when that is what you mean, as OMG Ponies pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can order_status be NULL?  If so, you'll need to say (order_status <> 5 OR order_status IS NULL).

Comment: @mahle: Order status *can* be null if you're using a left join.